# Excel VBA to MS Access - Query not getting executed

Tags: excel, ms-access

The code below gives an error "No value given for one or more parameters" and stops at the line : rs.open qry, cn

However if the other qry which is currently commented out (SELECT * FROM CallData) is executed, then the code runs without any problem.

What modifications do I need to make for the code to run correctly with the GROUP BY Query?

```
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim qry As String
    Dim Insertws As Worksheet
    Dim strConnectString As String
    Set Insertws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("temp")
    Insertws.Cells.Clear
   strConnectString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\corpfiler09\26663700_N01\NewAstt\ASTT.MDB;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=test;"
    'Connect Database; insert a new table
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    'qry = "SELECT * FROM CallData;"
    qry = "SELECT Bank, Count(Bank) from CallData where TicketDate = Date  GROUP BY Bank"
```

`cn.Open strConnectString
rs.Open qry, cn`

Comment: When access thinks a parameter is required it actually means it doesn't recognise a keyword. If Date is a function you probably need to use this instead: `Date()` (as per Jens answer)

Answer (score 0):

I'd write the query like this:

```
SELECT CallData.Bank, Count(CallData.Bank) AS CountOfBank
FROM CallData
GROUP BY CallData.Bank, CallData.TicketDate
HAVING (((CallData.TicketDate)=Date()));
```